# Typical way of hosting a Ruby WebSocket service that uses gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, websocket

While developing JavaScript apps, I usually create an API app, totally separate from the UI app. For the API, I usually use Sinatra.

I'm developing a JavaScript app that will use a WebSocket service I build. I'd like to use Ruby (em-websocket for now) and ActiveModel for data models. I want to keep this really lightweight, like a Sinatra app is for a RESTful API.

It seems my WebSocket service will simply be a ruby script invoked via "ruby web_socket_service.rb". I'd like to be able to use various gems (like activerecord, capistrano, and nokogiri) with this WebSocket service. What's the most typical way of accomplishing this?

Would I be better off creating a standalone gem to contain my models and the WebSocket service script and then host my WebSocket service from that? Or maybe simply include the gems and models directly in the script via "gem 'name'? Or, is there some special library or framework commonly-used to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a Rails app. That's the approach I would take if your WebSocket service starts to grow towards a medium-sized app. I.e. `bin`, `lib`, `Rakefile`, and a `Gemfile` for your gems and bundler.

For smaller apps you can still use a `Gemfile` and bundler to manage the included gems. This locks gem versions so you won't have conflicts if you deploy to other servers. And then just put everything into one or two script files, similar to Sinatra.

Creating standalone gems is really only useful for libraries or application parts that are reusable across many applications. This doesn't sound like that sort of thing.

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize I could just put a Gemfile file into a directory and run bundler. Awesome!